# Remove rows of short/long strings from column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe with a column of strings and a column of ID

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df

ID   Sentence                           
0    The cat is running away
1    The lazy dog jumped over the brown fox just now 
2    Hello
```

What I would like to do is to remove rows that have too short or too long strings. For example, I want to set a minimum of the strings to be 2 words and a maximum of 8 words. After filtering out the threshold, only ID#1 is returned.

```
ID   Sentence                           
0    The cat is running away
```

Could anyone give me a suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello this can be done by creating a new column that contains a count of the words then filter your df.

```
 df["Sentence"]=df["Sentence"].str.split()
 df["WordsCount"]=df["Sentence"].apply(lambda x: len(x))
 df=df[(df["WordsCount"]>= 2)&(df["WordsCount"]<=8)]
```